# CSS help positioning divs inline

Tags: html, css

I need help with a recurring problem that happens a lot.  I want to create a header that consists of 3 sections which are positioned inline.  I display them inline using the following css code:  `display: inline & float: left`The problem is that when I resize my browser window the last div is pushed down and isn't displayed inline.  I know it sounds like I'm being picky, but I don't want the design to distort as the visitor change's the monitor screen.  I have provided the html and css code below that I am working with below.  Hopefully I have explained this well enough.  Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div class="masthead-wrapper">
&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="searchbar-wrapper">
&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="profile-menu-wrapper">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #C0C0C0;
}
.masthead-wrapper {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #3b5998;
}
.searchbar-wrapper {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 560px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #FF0000;
}
.profile-menu-wrapper {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #00FF00;
}
```

Comment: <div id="Header"><div class="main1"></div></div> should be wrapped around html

Answer (score 2):

> display them inline using the following css code: `display: inline` & `float: left`

Aside... You are actually floating the element, not displaying it inline. The `display:inline` rule is irrelevant here since floated elements are implicitly displayed as *block*.

But anyway, your problem is that your sections are all of a fixed width (200 + 560 + 200 = 960px), so when the browser window reduces to near this width (960px plus a bit more for your page margins) the design is going to break - your containers wrap.

If you still want these containers to be fixed width and to simply be cropped on a smaller browser window then you could perhaps add `overflow:hidden` to your #Header. At least then it won't push the #Header height down beyond 80px (which is a problem you seem to be experiencing). But content will be hidden on the smaller screen.

Or, make all your column containers dynamic and give them percentage widths, so that they flex with the available width. eg. 20%, 60% and 20% respectively. Although this might make the widths too small or too large at some window sizes. You could add a `min-width` and `max-width` (with an absolute amount) to limit this. But at narrow widths `height:80px` is not going to be enough, so `min-height:80px` would perhaps be more appropriate, if your design allows for your #Header to be flexible?

Comment: overflow:hidden didn't help.  When I resize my browser I'd like the section of the header to stay the same (not disappear).

Comment: Add the `overflow:hidden` and remove the `float:left`

Comment: @StephRose: Why do you suggest removing `float:left`? If you remove any of the floats then the header sections will just be hidden from the start.

Comment: @JaPerk14: I'm not sure that I follow. Can you perhaps add an image of the desired result to your question? With the current dimensions set on the 3 sections of the header, if the width reduces to around 960px then _something_ is going to get hidden. You can prevent the right-most section from wrapping by giving the #Header a fixed width (`width:960px`) but then the #Header is still going to get cropped. You can use percentage widths (as mentioned in my answer), but there is a limit to how much content can be squashed in an ever decreasing space.

Answer (score 0):

With the percentage, be sure to no have padding on your columns. The padding will be add some width. For your header, you can use the position:fixed, and for IE6 and 7 use position: absolute ( the position :fixed ) doesn't work for them.
For the columns, you can add the clearfix method who can help you for placing without problem the rest of the content.
Your HTML can be something like this :

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
  <div id="col01">Column 01</div>
  <div id="col02">Column 02</div>
  <div id="col03">Colunm 03</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
    #header {
    position: fixed;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    }

    #col01,
    #col02,
    #col03 {
    float:left;
    }
    #col01,
    #col03 {
    width:20%;
    }
    #col02 {
    width:60%;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    .clearfix {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    html[xmlns] .clearfix {
        display: block;
    }


* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Hope it's helping you :-)